# Admin panel: Javascript not loading properly. Cannot edit pages/posts

Tags: wp-admin, jquery, pages, javascript

I am using the latest Wordpress.org install. None of my back-end javascript is working, none of my navigation drop downs, admin panel areas are not loading as well.

**I have not edited any core files.**

I have tried to disable all my plugins, even moved them from the plugin directory to see if there is a conflict. No luck.

I have tried to use different themes. No Luck.

The only way that I can edit posts/pages is if I highlight the text that's in the post (see screenshot).

I've added a few jquery scripts to my themes header.php file, tried to take those out as well, didn't work. Tried switching themes, didn't work. The only theme file that I've touched otherwise was functions.php.

I'm working on a local machine using WAMP.

Any help would be appreciated, THANK YOU!

SCREENSHOTS: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Dumb question I need to ask - had you checked that JS is not disabled in your browser globally or for local site?

Comment: Did you try clearing cache to your browser and load the site again? Also your wordpress screenshot looks like its a old version you also want to download a new version of wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the **wp-admin** and **wp-include** folders only with fresh copies from a zip of WordPress, matching version of course.

Sounds like a corrupt or missing file in one of the above folders.

Alternatively, if the above doesn't help, switch themes(only temporarily) to determine if the problem is theme related.

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try. Already tried 3 different themes and that didn't help. I'll report back with what I find.

Comment: Replaced both directories and that did not work.

Comment: Must be something in your theme then, if you've already ruled out plugins. Beyond that i can only see a server misconfiguration being at fault, make any config changes recently? (Also, have you tried restarting the server? ie. the wamp server)..

Comment: I've restarted the server and changed themes. Maybe I need to reinstall wamp

Comment: If the WAMP installation was working previously it would strike me a little odd that it just suddenly stopped working. Did you make any config changes recently, such as setting up new virtual hosts or re-configuring the htaccess file? Anything you can think of..

Comment: I did nothing out of the ordinary with my config files, though, after I rebooted my computer the drive that WAMP is on did a drive check which found some errors. That could possibly be the problem.

Comment: Reinstalled WAMP in another directory on a different drive. Was still broken. Going to do a full reinstall of wordpress and see what's up.

Comment: It looks like my database was corrupt,somehow destroying my back end. Luckily I had a back up. I lost a few hours of work, but it will be easy to replace because I have back ups of template files as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry to hear about your lost work(that's never nice), but good to hear you found the source of the problem and i'm happy to help.. :)

Comment: Thanks t310s. I'm glad the WP community is so helpful. I plan on diving into WP a lot more after this project and once I get a really good understanding of it I will definitely be back to help others out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after migrating from my localhost for a web server.

I noticed that there were differences between the load-scripts.php that was being generated by localhost and what was being generated by the web server. The web server was generating "double quotes" on some parts of que code!

THE SOLUTION (in my case): I compared both php.ini and noticed that on my web server the options of "magic_quotes" were enabled. Disable them (like on localhost's php.ini) and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

FTP into your site and open up your wp-config.php file.

Add this line:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Make sure you add this before:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```